# Spring Boot 2 + Hibernate 5 - how can I reset QueryPlanCache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

In my application, I have an HQL query that uses the `IN` operator - this query is called very often, with different number of parameters which means that Hibernate's `QueryPlanCache` caches every single variation of it separately - with 1,2,3...10...1200 elements, etc.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to exclude only the HQL query that contains the `IN`
  operator from being cached in the query plan cache - perhaps an annotation?
- Is there a way to programatically reset this cache? I saw that the `QueryPlanCache` class has a `clear()` method which is `public` but I couldn't figure out how you would go about calling it in a Spring Boot application.
- Is there some kind of filtering mechanism or class that I could implement and use? An interceptor that fires before the methods for the `QueryPlanCache` so I can filter out the problematic query in it?

Thank you in advance!